# Google Sheets IMPORTXML XPath help (understanding how to read a page source)

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to write a function that will give me the annual payout dividend for a given stock. The website I am using is www.seekingalpha.com

So I understand that the function is `=IMPORTXML (URL, xpath_query)`.
In that case, my URL is: https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/VOO/dividends/scorecard
but the problem I am having is figuring out the correct XPath to acquire the dividend value.

I currently have this as my function:

```
 =IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://www.seekingalpha.com/symbol/", $B2, "/dividends/scorecard"), "//body")
```

$B2 is a cell that holds the ticker symbol if you are wondering. Anyways, I right-clicked the number I wanted from the website and followed it downstream and tried seeing where it is nested under but keep running into the wrong "directory" per se, because I am usually left with an error "Empty."

I have also tried copying the xPath directly:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/section/section[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]
```

but am greeted with another empty field error.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I've been researching this for a while and figured this would be a great way to learn. Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

you need some other source. Google Sheets does not support scraping of JavaScript elements. you can test JS dependency simply by disabling JS for given site and what's left can be scraped. in your case its nothing:

[image]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://stocknews.com/stock/"&A15&"/dividends/", 
 "//div[@class='grade-cat-ytd']"), 2)
```

[image: 0]

> understanding how to read a page source

[image: 0]

Comment: does this mean I need to grab my data from another website?

Comment: @user3156068 yes indeed

Comment: I tried this website and got the same results:
=IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://www.stocknews.com/stock/", $B2, "/dividends/"), "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/article/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div")

Comment: the annual dividend payout for any given stock!

Comment: look for VOO Anuual Dividend